# Filtering a list of strings based on contents

Tags: python, list

Given the list `['a','ab','abc','bac']`, I want to compute a list with strings that have `'ab'` in them. I.e. the result is `['ab','abc']`. How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

This simple filtering can be achieved in many ways with Python. The best approach is to use "list comprehensions" as follows:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
>>> [k for k in lst if 'ab' in k]
['ab', 'abc']
```

Another way is to use the `filter` function. In Python 2:

```
>>> filter(lambda k: 'ab' in k, lst)
['ab', 'abc']
```

In Python 3, it returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) instead of a list, but you can cast it:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda k: 'ab' in k, lst))
['ab', 'abc']
```

Though it's better practice to use a comprehension.

Comment: @S.Lott: why? What's wrong with learning useful advanced programming topics in a suitable context?

Comment: @Edi Bendersky: Because they're more confusing than useful?  Because it leads to questions that are answered by "use a def"?  Because it rarely leads to anything better than code golf?  I don't know, they seem useless to me, after 30 years of programming in a wide variety of languages.  But I guess they're really important to you.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think lambdas are facilitating the consideration of functions as first-class objects, which is important for some programming paradigms. I wouldn't say they're *very important to me*, but I believe even newbies can benefit from thinking about programming this way, and definitely wouldn't call it *inflicting*.

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: I'm guessing they're important because you don't have a lot of reasons for using them.  Considering that SO has more questions on `lambda` than on `def`, I'm guessing that lambda really *is* confusing and hard to understand.  I'm not sure that a lambda helps much because it's the `filter` function that forces one to think about functional programming.  Any example with `filter` (like this one) is good stuff for showing functional programming.  Omitting the lambda -- IMO -- makes it an even better way to show the power of functional programming.

Comment: @S.Lott: but isn't `lambda` the perfect companion to `filter` in this case? I think that writing a separate function just for checking if `ab` is in the given list is an overkill. So is writing a more general function that basically wraps the `in` operator. How would you use `filter` in a clearer way without `lambda` here?

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: No.  I find that lambda is not the *perfect* companion to much of anything.  I would use `def` and I would find it less confusing; I would probably have to answer one fewer question on  lambda.  And the answer wouldn't look like code golf.  As I said, the `filter` is good.  I have found that a simple `def` will not harm the importance of n00bs learning how `filter` works.

Comment: It's not only n00bs who find this answer

Comment: I am a n00b and now I am introduced to lambda. feeling awesome to know it. now I will learn more about it.

Comment: I had to surround the filter with a list() function to get a list back otherwise I get a filter object. Don't know if this is due to the python version (I use 3.5)

Comment: And I learned about lambda and a new expression 'code golf' ^^ great SO question here

Comment: @EliBendersky: The best practice is to use list comprehension since it tends to be more efficient. Running a small simulation, below, we have that using a list, filter and a lambda makes the process nearly 4 times slower. 

`%%timeit for i in range(10000): a = [k for k in lst if 'ab' in k]` 

`%%timeit for i in range(10000): a = list(filter(lambda k: 'ab' in k, lst))`

Answer (score 26):

```
[x for x in L if 'ab' in x]
```

Answer (score 23):

```
# To support matches from the beginning, not any matches:

items = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
prefix = 'ab'

filter(lambda x: x.startswith(prefix), items)
```

Comment: avoid list as variable name since this is a python object type.

Answer (score 8):

Tried this out quickly in the interactive shell:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
>>> [x for x in l if 'ab' in x]
['ab', 'abc']
>>>
```

Why does this work? Because the [`in` operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) is defined for strings to mean: "is substring of".

Also, you might want to consider writing out the loop as opposed to using the [list comprehension syntax](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) used above:

```
l = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
result = []
for s in l:
   if 'ab' in s:
       result.append(s)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
mylist = ['a', 'ab', 'abc']
assert 'ab' in mylist
```