# Auto unzip of password-protected rar files in python

Tags: python, rar

recently started to learn python and there was a problem .... I need to unzip the rar file, which is password protected, but the password is written in the file name, which is in the archive. And so ~ 300 times. How, with what and where can this be implemented?
For example, there is an archive 383442389.rar, it has two files, pass-1337643656.data (the name contains the archive password) and the following archive)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure of all the context of your question, but I will try  to answer you.

1. You said that you need to unzip a file .rar, but that is not possible, if the file is .rar you need to unrar
2. If you need just to unzip a .zip

something like that should work

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('test1.zip', 'r') as myzip:
    myzip.extractall(pwd='<password>')
```

3. In the case of .rar

pip install rarfile (installed only in python 3)

```
from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile('test2.rar', 'r') as myrar:
    myrar.extractall(pwd='<password>')
```

4. you mention that the password comes in the .rar like a name of file

   - pass-1337643656.data
   - you can list the names of the files using

> RarFile.namelist() Return a list of archive members by name.

So you can extract the password using split

```
s = 'pass-1337643656.data'
s.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]
print(s)
```

> '1337643656'

you can use also a regular expression to extract that

**Conclusion.**

A complete solution using .rar  could be

```
from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile('test2.rar', 'r') as myrar:
    file_names = myrar.namelist()
    pass_file = list(filter(lambda k: 'pass' in k, l))[0]
    pass = pass_file.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]
    myrar.extractall(pwd=pass)
```

**Reference.**

- https://python-unrar.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3/rarfile.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp
- [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html
- [Unzipping files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python)

Comment: Hello! Yes, I was a little mistaken with the words, I need a case with .rar. In this case, I still need to do the code execution up to 300 times (so that only the final result appears in C: \ Users \ Usero \ Desktop). Still, how can I specify the path to test2.rar? Here is an example of such a rar file, you can look at the link: https://myfile.is/h0325b00o8/Enclosed_rar (Also, when compiling, an error occurs: Syntax error in C: \ Users \ Usero \ script.py
  File "C: \ Users \ script.py", line 5
     pass = pass_file..split ('-') [1] .split ('.') [0]
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IgorBezrodnyy I set the path relative to the current folder where I have my script 
in this line with ```RarFile('test2.rar', 'r') as myrar:``, I you read the referece that I let you regarding to rarfile you can see the specification of the constructor of  the object ```RarFile```,  as you can see here ``` rarfile.RarFile(file[, mode='r'])``` where file should be a path to a file

Comment: Regarding to the syntax error in the message you can see there are 2 unnecessary points  ```pass_file..split ('-') [1] .split ('.') [0]```, maybe an error of copy and paste , because of in the answer I didn't see that error, should be 
```pass_file.split ('-') [1] .split ('.') [0]```

Comment: @IgorBezrodnyy The idea of stackoverflow isn't to solve all your problem, just clarify something more specifically,  that maybe you don't know or a weird I know that you are a new user of stackoverflow, I think that you need to double check  this page
https://stackoverflow.com/tour