# Search an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, search

I have an array that looks something like this

```
Arr = ["Jackson", "Greg", "Leon", "Jay", Leia]
```

And I need to filter it like this:

```
Input: Ja
Output: Jackson, Jay

Input: Jack
Output: Jackson

Input: e
Output: Greg, Leon, Leia

Input: Le
Output: Leon, Leia

Input: Leia
Output: Leia
```

I've tried this:

```
for each in KeyWord:
    search = each + '+'
    output = []
    for i in Arr:
        if(re.findall(each, i)):
            output.append(i)
            cock2 = "Search Results:\n===========\n"
            for x in output:
              Arr += x + "\n"
```

Where Arr contains the list of names.

An example of what this algorithm would return is

```
Input: Leia
Output: Leon, Leia
```

Comment: Hints: (1) Your search modifies your original list (Arr), that's probably not what you want. (and it should fail anyway, as you're trying to concatenate a list and a string) (2) You can use ``in`` to check if a string contains another string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably better off to use operator `in` instead of regular expression.

```
# Finding all words in Arr that matches KeyWord
output = []
for word in Arr:
    if KeyWord in word:
        output.append(word)
```

or,

```
output = [word for word in Arr if Keyword in word]
```

If you still want to use regular expression, checkout https://pythonexamples.org/python-re-findall/.