# I've a python list of items and I'm trying to get only CN values from that list using regex

Tags: python, regex

Here is my list:

```sh
lst = ['CN=21234433,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDIr,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC','CN=22341332,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDir,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC','CN=22343332-GCP,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDir,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC']
```

I'm looking output something like this:

output:

```
['21234433','22341332', 22343332-GCP]
```

i've tried using this regex: `reg = r'\br\d+'`. it has not worked for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents)

Comment: @Anamitra thanks for your reply no i'm getting a different output

Comment: @xdhmoore i've tried using this regex: reg = r'\br\d+' . it is not worked for me

Comment: Use this: `[re.split('[=,]', x)[1] for x in lst if x.startswith("CN=")]`

Comment: @anubhava thank you. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `startsWith + split` from list like this:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['CN=21234433,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDIr,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC','CN=22341332,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDir,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC','CN=22343332-GCP,OU=ABBCPeople,DC=InfoDir,DC=Prod,DC=ABBC']
>>> [re.split('[=,]', x)[1] for x in lst if x.startswith("CN=")]
['21234433', '22341332', '22343332-GCP']
```

- Using `startswith` we pick only items that start with `CN=`
- Using `re.split('[=,]', x)` we split on `=` or `,` and using `[1]` we pick 1st element from resulting array

Answer (score 1):

Are the CN values always at the same position in the list, or are the positions arbitrary? In case of the former, just index. I assume the latter. In that case, you can loop over the items, check if "CN=" is in the string, and if so: add it to the list. And lastly, delete the "CN=" part.

```
lst = ['CN=21234433','OU=ABBCPeople', 'DC=InfoDIr','DC=Prod','DC=ABBC','CN=22341332','OU=ABBCPeople','DC=InfoDir','DC=Prod','DC=ABBC','CN=22343332-GCP','OU=ABBCPeople','DC=InfoDir','DC=Prod','DC=ABBC']

output = [i.replace("CN=", "") for i in lst if "CN=" in i]
```

Output: `['21234433', '22341332', '22343332-GCP']`

Comment: @KRISHNACHAITANYARYALI that's really you, the solutions works with the input you provided (granted you have the strings properly formatted).