# Python 3: how to filter list of packages?

Tags: python

How do I filter this list to show only items that match a substring? The following code shows an ordered list of Python packages installed for a Jupyter notebook.

```
import pkg_resources

dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
# Filter out distributions you don't care about and use.
dists.reverse()
dists
```

I tried:

```
list(filter(lambda k: "fsspec" in k, dists))
```

but get the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'Distribution' is not iterable
```

I tried copying the pattern of the solution here: [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents)

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Could you give an example input, and the desired output from that input?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to filter a class object with filter. Either you want to convert it to string or change the filter method accordingly. For this usecase, the below code should work fine.

```
import pkg_resources

dists = [d.project_name for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
# Filter out distributions you don't care about and use.
dists.reverse()
lst = list(filter(lambda k: "fsspec" in k, dists))
print(lst)
```

Generally to debug type errors, try to get the type of the variable you're working with using type() and if it is a class you can use the __dict__ attribute to print out its properties for a better perspective on what you need to do.

Comment: thanks. how would i modify your code to search for multiple packages rather than just 'fsspec'?

Comment: I think this should do it:
`lst = list(filter(lambda k: any(x in k for x in reqs), dists))`
hit up the python docs if you don't understand the any function.