# How to access element in nested list with condition in python

Tags: python

I have a nested list and I need to filter out a key / value based on a condition.

the list:

```
[{'buyer': False,
  'commission': '0.01333920',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52549382,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2448678953,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3334.80',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.34800',
  'realizedPnl': '0',
  'side': 'SELL',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628311810877},
 {'buyer': True,
  'commission': '0.01334440',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52544760,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447909783,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3336.10',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.36100',
  'realizedPnl': '-0.29400000',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628309268672},
 {'buyer': False,
  'commission': '0.01322680',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52532126,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447909485,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3306.70',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.06700',
  'realizedPnl': '0',
  'side': 'SELL',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628301912771},
 {'buyer': True,
  'commission': '0.01319760',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52525468,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447502727,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3299.40',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '32.99400',
  'realizedPnl': '-0.29700000',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628297857042},
```

Now, how can I get the 'time' value of the nested block where the 'id' is equal to 52532126 ? Although I prefer vectorization I tried to iterate through the list but I had no success.

```
for item in response_tradelist:
    if item == '52532126':
        print('ok')
```

Even If it would work how do I get the 'time' value in the corresponding block?

Comment: You could try `print([item for item in response_tradelist if item['id'] == 52532126])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a list of dictionaries, you must compare with `id` in each item and then print the `time` if `id` is a match.

Also `id` value is not a string, so don't use quotes around `id`.

Try this:

```
for item in response_tradelist:
    if item['id'] == 52532126:
        print(item['time'])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the dictionary with id 52532126:

```
for dic in response_tradelist:
    if dic['id'] == 52532126:
        print(dic)
```

if you want time specifically, replace `print(dic)` with:

```
print(dic['time'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of your id is in integer in that block of dictionary, thus you cannot check with string value,
you need to check value like item['id']== 52532126

```
l=[{'buyer': False,
  'commission': '0.01333920',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52549382,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2448678953,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3334.80',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.34800',
  'realizedPnl': '0',
  'side': 'SELL',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628311810877},
 {'buyer': True,
  'commission': '0.01334440',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52544760,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447909783,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3336.10',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.36100',
  'realizedPnl': '-0.29400000',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628309268672},
 {'buyer': False,
  'commission': '0.01322680',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52532126,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447909485,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3306.70',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '33.06700',
  'realizedPnl': '0',
  'side': 'SELL',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628301912771},
 {'buyer': True,
  'commission': '0.01319760',
  'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
  'id': 52525468,
  'maker': False,
  'marginAsset': 'USDT',
  'orderId': 2447502727,
  'positionSide': 'BOTH',
  'price': '3299.40',
  'qty': '0.010',
  'quoteQty': '32.99400',
  'realizedPnl': '-0.29700000',
  'side': 'BUY',
  'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
  'time': 1628297857042}]

for d in l:
    if d["id"]==52532126:
        print(d["time"])
```

and if you want to print the whole dictionary then ,

```
 for d in l:
    if d["id"]==52532126:
        print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there. You only need to access the right element instead of just `item` and the ID value is an `int` not an `str`

Fixing those two things gives you the result:

```
for item in response_tradelist:
    if item['id'] == 52532126:
        print('ok')
```

you can [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) using a `filter` function in case you have multiple values and want to retrieve a list.

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == 52525468, response_tradelist))
```

reference: [Filtering a list of strings based on contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2152908/5236575)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a dict

```
for item in response_tradelist:
    if item['id] == '52532126':
        print(item['time'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate thru the list of dictionaries and check the i["time"] index for each one.

```py
dictList = [{
    'buyer': False,
    'commission': '0.01333920',
    'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
    'id': 52549382,
    'maker': False,
    'marginAsset': 'USDT',
    'orderId': 2448678953,
    'positionSide': 'BOTH',
    'price': '3334.80',
    'qty': '0.010',
    'quoteQty': '33.34800',
    'realizedPnl': '0',
    'side': 'SELL',
    'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
    'time': 1628311810877
    },
    {
    'buyer': True,
    'commission': '0.01334440',
    'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
    'id': 52544760,
    'maker': False,
    'marginAsset': 'USDT',
    'orderId': 2447909783,
    'positionSide': 'BOTH',
    'price': '3336.10',
    'qty': '0.010',
    'quoteQty': '33.36100',
    'realizedPnl': '-0.29400000',
    'side': 'BUY',
    'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
    'time': 1628309268672
    },
    {
    'buyer': False,
    'commission': '0.01322680',
    'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
    'id': 52532126,
    'maker': False,
    'marginAsset': 'USDT',
    'orderId': 2447909485,
    'positionSide': 'BOTH',
    'price': '3306.70',
    'qty': '0.010',
    'quoteQty': '33.06700',
    'realizedPnl': '0',
    'side': 'SELL',
    'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
    'time': 1628301912771},
    {
    'buyer': True,
    'commission': '0.01319760',
    'commissionAsset': 'USDT',
    'id': 52525468,
    'maker': False,
    'marginAsset': 'USDT',
    'orderId': 2447502727,
    'positionSide': 'BOTH',
    'price': '3299.40',
    'qty': '0.010',
    'quoteQty': '32.99400',
    'realizedPnl': '-0.29700000',
    'side': 'BUY',
    'symbol': 'MKRUSDT',
    'time': 1628297857042
    }]

searchValue = 1628297857042

for i in dictList:
    if i["time"] == searchValue:
        print(f"Found: {i["time"]}")
```

Alternatively if you were looking to do some "fun" python magic -

```py
value = [True for item in dictList if item["time"] == searchValue]
print(value)
```

You could use list comprehension, unfortunately it does return an array, but that could be fixed pretty easily.